# SelectPdf add page numbering outside footer

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, selectpdf

I'm using SelectPdf in my ASP.NET Core Web API, it's possible to show page numbering outside footer? In middle of the page for an example.

Any help?

Comment: Hi @Marcelo Antunes Fernandes, what do you mean `In the middle of the page`? Middle location of the page content? If you do not want to add the page number you can add it to the header.

Comment: Hi @Rena, In my case I render header with a custom HTML. It's possible to add page numbering in header?

Comment: Hi @Marcelo Antunes Fernandes, it is better for you to share enough code.